# Do I have to install Android Studio again after updating windows to windows 10?

Tags: windows, android-studio

I have Windows 7, and need to migrate to Windows 10 because I must install Visual Studio (which doesn't work on Win7 anymore). As I read, Windows 10 online update does not delete any of my files or programs.

What would happen to my Android Studio, will it work same as before, after update is preformed?

**UPDATE:** Windows 10 could not detect my second monitor, everything else is doing fine for now. I found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/windows-10-second-monitor-windows-10-say-it-cannot/3e7a6e44-18a6-4971-a8e3-71cb883dc1f4) helpful for second monitor solution. Just updating nvidia and reboot did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have to reinstall the software when I upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10. It worked just fine for me.

According to the site below, if you’re running Windows 7, you can preserve Windows settings, personal files, and most apps during the upgrade to Windows 10.

http://www.intowindows.com/you-can-upgrade-to-windows-10-preview-without-losing-installed-programs/